# HTHorizontalSelectionList unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

..and I'll tell you why:

I'm using the following pod: [HTHorizontalSelectionList](https://github.com/hightower/HTHorizontalSelectionList)

If I declare it like this:

```
class RightViewController: UIViewController, HTHorizontalSelectionListDelegate, HTHorizontalSelectionListDataSource {

    var selectionList: HTHorizontalSelectionList!
}
```

I get the following error on compilation:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FTest'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HTHorizontalSelectionList", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo25HTHorizontalSelectionList in RightViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Huh!? *What*!?

If I instead implement it like this it compiles fine!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var selectionList: HTHorizontalSelectionList!
    selectionList?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)
    selectionList?.delegate = self
    selectionList?.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(selectionList)
}
```

...except of course, I get an error on the `addSubview` line:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'm finding it incredibly difficult to understand how Swift works when I get stuff like this happening quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm finding it incredibly difficult to understand how Swift works when I get stuff like this happening quite often

There is nothing difficult about this. You are starting out with your Optional variable set to `nil`. It stays `nil`. Eventually you try to unwrap `nil` and then you crash, because you can't do that:

```
var selectionList: HTHorizontalSelectionList! // it is nil
selectionList?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40) // still nil, nothing happens
selectionList?.delegate = self // still nil, nothing happens
selectionList?.dataSource = self // still nil, nothing happens
self.view.addSubview(selectionList) // unwrap, crash
```

If you don't want to crash, assign `selectionList` an actual value other than `nil`, like maybe an actual HTHorizontalSelectionList.

Comment: Oh, I see! However, doing something like `selectionList = HTHorizontalSelectionList()` doesn't compile and gives me that original error.

Comment: Okay, then you need to focus on that; it's completely different, it's a linker error. I answered the code question. :)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by assigning `selectionList` an actual value?

Comment: Exactly as you said. "Assign" means use an equal sign. For example, `var selectionList =  HTHorizontalSelectionList(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30))`

Comment: Understood. So... it's still incredibly difficult because I get compilation errors based simply on assigning something in Swift.

Comment: No, the error you cited first is not a compilation error. It is a linker error.

Comment: How can a linker error occur simply because of assigning something? I think I need a break.

Comment: It probably has to do with how you've installed the pod. But that is a different question. Your question was about the "unexpectedly found nil" runtime crash, and I explained that. I suggest you break the linker error off into a new question. I'm not a pod person (don't they come from outer space) so I can't help with that...